# Conditional Component in React based on return of api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, fetch

I'm creating a status icon based on whether an object has a certain amount of errors.

What's the best way to pass the data from ComponentDidMount to the function I want to evaluate the data in.
I'm attempting to add up the status in an object, but
getting `TypeError: error.filter is not a function`

```js
import React from 'react';

class PolicyIcon extends React.Component {
  state = {
    errors: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let initialErrors = [];
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/status/2/errors')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ errors: data });
      });
  }

  addErrors = errors => {
    console.log(errors);
    errors.filter((x, i) => {
      return x.isError >= 5;
    }).length;
  };

  statusCircle = errors => {
    return this.addErrors(errors) ? (
      <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle
          cx="50"
          cy="50"
          r="40"
          stroke="black"
          stroke-width="3"
          fill="red"
        />
      </svg>
    ) : (
      <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle
          cx="50"
          cy="50"
          r="40"
          stroke="black"
          stroke-width="3"
          fill="green"
        />
      </svg>
    );
  };

  render() {
    <div>{this.statusCircle(this.state.errors)}</div>;
  }
}

export default UserIcon;
```

Comment: You save the conditions in the state, so you don't need to pass them. You just use `this.state.conditions`. Also in render you have `<statusCircle />`, but 'statusCircle' is a function, not a component. Should have it as `<div>{this.statusCircle()}</div>`. (P.S. don't forget, at the moment you don't have a default state, so 'this.state.conditions' will be undefined until you set it in the API call)

Comment: @Jayce444 Thanks for the input, based on what you said I made some changes and updated the question. I'm getting some more errors but is it looking better now?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of advice that I can give you with this code. Firstly, you are coupling your code very hard. Meaning, you are giving your icons so much task to conduct. It is responsible data retrieval and defining the UI. Below I have laid out a way for you to do what you want and a very neat structure as well.

```
const UserIcon = ({state}) => (
 <svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle
    cx="50"
    cy="50"
    r="40"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="3"
    fill="{state === 'error' ? 'red' : 'green'}"
  />
 </svg>
);
```

As you can see, the UserIcon is solely responsible for the user display. Now, we should write a separate class based component that will do the fetching and data manipulation.

```
class UserIconManager extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { errors: 0, loaded: false }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/user/2/status')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ errors: data.errors, loaded: true})
 }

 render() {
   const { errors, loaded } = this.state;
   const iconState = errors >= 5 ? 'error': null
   return loaded ? 
    <UserIcon state={iconState} /> :
    null
 }
}
```

I am not sure about the specifics of what you are trying to do but im pretty sure my example is 100% relevant. Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it looks much simpler. However, I don't see where you are counting up the errors, am I missing it? What is loading doing? Also I am getting two errors with this: UserIconManaager.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: In the `UserIconManager` render, he has `const iconState = errors >= 5 ? 'error': null`, that's where he checks if there are 5 or more errors. Also for that error, in the `UserIconManager` render, change the return to `return loaded ? <UserIcon state={iconState} /> : null`

Comment: whoops didnt expect you to just directly paste my code. I was programming straight from memory off my pc. I changed the line to return `null` if the data was not fetched yet. I improvised with the `loading` variable. basically no icon will show up till you get your data back.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that using `componentWillMount` to handle side effect like querying API is not recommended by React itself: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount, aslo `componentWillMount` has been planned to be deprecated and will become `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` since React 17. The API fetching should be done insde `componentDidMount` instead.

Comment: @ThaiDuongTran I agree. its been changed